# Vertical lines from x-axis breaks up to geom_line() ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to recreate the following graph made in excel using ggplot2:

[image]

This is what I've got so far:

[image]

As you can see, the only thing I lack are the vertical lines that go from the x-axis up to the line. Does anyone know how to implement them? I know there's a method similar to abline() for ggplot, but I don't know how to make it stop in the line.

Comment: `geom_segment()` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!